# Is there a sockJS client for native Android apps?

Tags: android, client, native, sockjs, primus

I'm using Primus with SockJS as my socket server, and I wonder if theres a good native android client (java) for sockjs!

Thank you.

Comment: See WebSocketClient by koush: https://github.com/koush/android-websockets

Comment: Have you found any native Android client for SockJS?